# Golang not using a DB

Tags: database, go

I don't want to use a DB at this time, I'd like to keep data, as structs, in a file.
My question is how to organize and retrieve the data.

For example, I have:

```
type Foo struct{
 Id int
 Name string
}
type Bar struct{
 Id int
 Name string
}
```

I want to make a bunch of different Foos and Bars, then I want to be able to query/select particular Foos and Bars.
Would I make a package then a file in the package, for instance, foo/foo.go; and in foo.go have a method that makes all of the Foos, then another method that would accept, for example, a name, and then search for that particular Foo.

```
func MakeFoos(){
 //make the Foos here, and put them in a global array: []Foo ??
}

func GetFoo(name string) Foo{
 //this would search the array populated in MakeFoos() and return a Foo ??
}
```

Is this an ok start to hold data in memory as opposed to a DB in Go?
Any help and suggestions to get me going welcomed.

Comment: For fast searches of a lot of items, you need indexes, so you need a `map` per index that you maintain on insert/delete/update. To index and avoid data loss, you'll mostly end up implementing a (special-purpose) database yourself. In many applications, holding data in memory instead of a DB will cause you grief. [Here's a post on getting started with the gorm ORM and SQLite, if that helps](http://levi.guru/get-going-with-gorm-and-sqlite/).

Comment: You may not want to use a database at this time - but you're going to spend the next few months implementing 5% of a databases features by hand and they will be nowhere near as efficient. I suggest you consider using a database _right now_ to get up and running quicker.

Comment: sqlite is quite easy to use from GoLang and it doesn't involve installing a separate database... You can even have GoLang create the DB on startup (if it doesn't exist yet) and just start using it.  The indexing and such will make your life a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a GO project that does not use a database. Using slices, maps, linked lists, json, and the OS file system quite a bit can be accomplished without a database. I don't have a solution for you, but study up on the tools I just mentioned. All these tools are included in the standard Go libraries.